# Automate test flow changes if test response is x or y

Tags: testng, rest-assured

I have a test that passes if the response is x or y:

```
.assertThat().body("applicationStatusCode", oneOf("x", "y"))
```

but a third test needs to run if it's x, and **cannot** run if it is y

I have tried

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = "XYtest")
```

but bc XYtest needs to pass even if value is y, it attempts to run the third test

i looked at [Annotation Transformers](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) and [Beanshell](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell) but i don't think these accomplish what i want

Comment: I never do that, for all tests are independent, they don't rely on other tests' result.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 Is there a way to make this test independent of other tests' results?

Comment: Take 2 requests into one test, first request will be pre-condition for second request. Therefore, you have an independent test, doesn't rely on other test's result.